# Problema con anotación de tipo `list` en python 3.9

Tags: python, python-3.9

Se supone que a partir de python 3.9, las *anotación de tipos* de lista ya se pueden hacer directamente con el constructor `list`, sin necesitar importar el tipo `List` de `typing`.

Estaba construyendo un [generador de números primos](https://gist.github.com/chemacortes/d6572c9df29b1520b56b4bc73d4bd700), del que se puede extraer el siguiente código:

```py
from collections.abc import Generator


class Primes:
    def __init__(self):
        self.subprimes: list[int] = []


def gen_primes() -> Generator[int, None, None]:

    subprimes: list[int] = []

    for i in subprimes:
        yield i
```

Como se puede ver, uso la anotación `list[int]` en dos sitios. La primera no me da problema, pero en la segunda `mypy` me saca el siguiente error:

> error: "list" is not subscriptable, use "typing.List" instead

Esto no es cierto, ya que a partir de python 3.9 se permite *subscribir* `list`, tal como parece aceptar en la primera lista anotada.

¿Estoy haciendo algo mal o es que se trata de algún bug extraño?

Estoy usando `python 3.9.1` y `mypy 0.790`.

Muchas gracias.

---

**Editado** (08/feb/2021): la nueva versión de mypy 0.800 soporta python 3.9, con lo que ya no se produce este error.

Comment: El motivo por el que en el método __init__() no se produce el error, es que, al no tener ninguna anotación de tipos, este método probablemente no esté siendo chequeado por mypy.

Answer (score 2):

No utilizo mucho python, pero revisando la [documentación](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/#implementation), es probable que tu código esté bien, y mypy sea el error, pues la documentación dice lo siguiente.

> Usefulness of this syntax before PEP 585 is limited as external tooling like Mypy does not recognize standard collections as generic.

[PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585) hace referencia a **Type Hinting Generics In Standard Collections**, que es la adición al lenguaje que permite hacer exactamente lo que está en la pregunta

> Esto no es cierto, ya que a partir de python 3.9 se permite subscribir list, tal como parece aceptar en la primera lista anotada

Con eso, y con el hecho de que [Python 3.9.1](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-391/) salió apenas hace un mes (el 07/12/2020, y hoy, cuando escribo esta respuesta, es 09/01/2021), es de esperar que **mypy** todavía no reconozca las colecciones estándard.

Sin embargo, como establece PEP 585, python ya las soporta de forma nativa, así que no hay necesidad de utilizar mypy (por lo menos en el aspecto de type hinting con colecciones estándard).

Quizá en futuras versiones, agreguen soporte.

Comment: Tienes razón. He encontrado un ticket de mypy que tiene esta característica como _"feature"_ desde Noviembre 2020. Voy a explicarlo como respuesta. Muchas gracias por el interés.

Answer (score 2):

Según el ticket de mypy [#9761 "Supporting Python 3.9"](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/9761), mypy 0.791 aún no soporta las extensiones de python 3.9 para anotaciones `list[int]` (así como otros constructores habituales: `list`, `set`, `dict`, `tuple`).

En cambio, sí que funciona con las *colecciones estándar*. Si no se quiere esperar a la nueva versión de `mypy`, una buena solución sería usar la colección `MutableSequence`:

```py
from collections.abc import Generator, MutableSequence


class Primes:
    def __init__(self):
        self.subprimes: MutableSequence[int] = []


def gen_primes() -> Generator[int, None, None]:

    subprimes: MutableSequence[int] = []

    for i in subprimes:
        yield i
```

Aunque me temo que con el tiempo se hará más popular el uso de `list` que `MutableSequence` en las anotaciones de tipos.

---

**EDITADO**: diferencias entre `list` y `MutableSequence`.

Sólo por dejar constancia, `list` se puede considerar subclase de `Sequence/MutableSequence`, pero no equivalente.

Como puede leerse en el glosario:

> Los [Iteradores](https://docs.python.org/3.9/glossary.html#term-iterator) tienen que tener un método `__iter__()` que retornan a sí mismos como objetos iteradores, con lo que cada *iterador* es también *iterable* y puede ser usado en la mayoría de sitios que aceptan iterables. **Una notable excepción es el código que efectúa múltiples pasadas de iteración. Un objeto contenedor (como `list`) crea un nuevo iterador fresco cuando se pasa a la función `iter()` o cuando se usa en un *bucle for*. Si se intenta esto con un iterador se obtiene el mismo objeto iterador exhausto, resultado de la iteración anterior, lo que pasaría a verse como un contendor vacío.**

Si cambio `subprimes` para que sea `MutableSequence`, hay que tener en cuenta este problema con las múltiples iteraciones.

Por ejemplo:

```py
subprimes: MutableSequence[int]

for i in subprimes:
    yield i

for i in subprimes:
    yield i
```

Como instancias de `MutableSequence` podríamos usar `list` y `deque`.

Si usamos una lista, `subprimes = [...]`, ambos bucles recorrerán la lista por completo.

En cambio, si usamos `subprimes = deque([...])`, sólo se recorrerá la lista la primera vez, ya que el iterador permacerá exhausto cuando se realize el siguiente bucle.

En mi caso, necesito recorrer varias veces las listas, por lo que no es correcto que aparezcan anotadas con el tipo `MutableSequence`. A pesar del error que da *mypy*, dejaré la anotación correcta de `list[int]`.

Comment: Enredando hace unas semanas me paso lo mismo y supuse que tendría que ver con mypy, pero no le dedique tiempo a investigarlo. Gracias por tomarte el tiempo de traerlo aquí!!

Comment: En versiones de mypy en las que no puede indicarse list[int], puede importarse List del módulo typing. Lo mismo con Tuple, Dict, o Set.

Ejemplos:
numeros: List[int] = [1, 2, 3]
una_tupla: Tuple[int, str] = (2, 'dos'),
etc

Comment: Es lo que indico inicialmente en la pregunta. Pero si hacemos caso del _zen de python_: "Debería haber una, y preferiblemente solo una, manera obvia de hacerlo". Y la _forma obvia_ es usando los tipos `list` y `tuple` estándar.